# Hadoop split method

Tags: hadoop, split

I know and read many times Hadoop is not aware of what's inside the input file, and the  split depends on the InputFileFormat, but let's be more specific ... for example, i read GZIP is not splittable, so if i have a unique gzipped input file of 1 TB, and no one of the node have an hd of that size, what happens? input will be splitted but hadoop will add info about the dependencies between one chunk and others? 
 other question, if i have a huge .xml file, so basically text, how the split works, by line or by the configured MB of the block size?

Comment: You need to distinguish between block-splitting on the HDFS level and what the `InputFormat` creates. The latter is a meta-information that tells the MR job how to read the data, the former is a physical splitting on the HDD.

Comment: so i can phisically split the gzip input file across many nodes, but i can't split the local chunk across many job for the nature of the gzip format, im i right?... what happen in that case?

Comment: Yes exactly. What do you mean by what happens?

Comment: i mean how hadoop manage the described situation. i know he move the computation where the data is, but if the data is not splittable, but phisically on different nodes, how he perform the computation?

Comment: By reading it over the network, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

**BZIP2** is splittable in hadoop - it provides very good compression ratio but from CPU time and performances is not providing optimal results, as compression is very CPU consuming.

**LZO** is splittable in hadoop - leveraging **[hadoop-lzo](https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo)** you have splittable compressed LZO files. You need to have external .lzo.index files to be able to process in parallel. The library provides all means of generating these indexes in local or distributed manner.

**LZ4** is splittable in hadoop - leveraging **[hadoop-4mc](https://github.com/carlomedas/4mc)** you have splittable compressed 4mc files. You don't need any external indexing, and you can generate archives with provided command line tool or by Java/C code, inside/outside hadoop. 4mc makes available on hadoop LZ4 at any level of speed/compression-ratio: from fast mode reaching 500 MB/s compression speed up to high/ultra modes providing increased compression ratio, almost comparable with GZIP one.

**ZSTD** (zstandard) is now splittable as well in hadoop/Spark/Flink by leveraging **[hadoop-4mc](https://github.com/carlomedas/4mc)**.

Please have a look at Hadoop Elephant Bird to process complex input in your jobs. Anyways **XML** is not natively  splittable in EB or hadoop, AFAIK.